# Usage of "wenn überhaupt"

Tags: german-to-english

Please consider the following sentence:

> Muskelaufbautraining  ist der  sicherste  Schutz  vor  dem  Pflegeheim.  Doch  damit  fangen die meisten, wenn überhaupt, erst dann an, wenn gesundheitliche Probleme auftreten.

Which of the following meanings is correct:

1. Most, if not all, people don't start working out until health issues arise.
2. Most people don't start working out until health issues arise, if they do start any workout at all. (**In other words**: Most people don't start working out until health issues arise, or they don't start working out even then)

Answer (score 3):

With the unmodified example, meaning 2 applies.

For meaning 1 you would have to write:

> Die meisten, wenn nicht (sogar) alle, fangen erst mit Muskelaufbautraining an, wenn ...

Other example:

> Ich komme erst nachmittags ins Büro, wenn überhaupt.

(I arrive at the office in the afternoon, if at all.)

Comment: Many thanks to you. With the "unmodified example" do you mean this: »Most people don't start working out until health issues arise, if they do start any workout at all« ?

Comment: +1. It'sreally the same as "if at all", but the syntactic position may differ.